# Generate forms dynamically from database (multiple choice fields)

Tags: php, mysql

I generate html forms with php from datas stored in MySQL database.

It’s working fine but i was wondering how to deal with datas that should output in a html `<select>` (multiple choices)

Client sent me a csv file that i import in DB.

For simple form elements such as text input, text area, a field per line is easy to handle :

```
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| id   | name           | field_type      |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
|1     | client_name    |  text_input     |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
|2     | client_surname |  text_input     |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
|3     | client_adress  |  text_area      |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
```

he sent me some line in CSV that should be some select

```
+------+---------------------+--------------+
|4     | Choice (1, 2 or 3)  |  select      |
+------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Obviously, i can’t handle the select with this line.

What is the most effective way ? Should i create different lines with another column to group this fields

```
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
| id   | name           | field_type      |select_id |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
|4     | Choice 1       | select          | 1        |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
|5     | Choice 2       | select          | 1        |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
|6     | Choice 3       | select          | 1        |
+------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Or should I create an other table for this `<select>` and make a join, or store datas as serialized datas (an array of possible choice for this select)?

```
+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id   | name           | field_type  |value            |
+------+----------------+-------------------------------+
|4     | Choice         | select      | array(1,2,3)    |
+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Cleanest way is definitely to create a new table. To be practical, you could just store the choices as comma separated values in a column. However the latter choice disallows you to store meta data for each option like Id, class etc.

Comment: You could store the values as a JSON object in an extra column, that way you will be able to add extra metadata.